# How to sort a list of lists based on values of another list of lists?

Tags: python, python-3.x, sorting

My two list of lists are:

```
lst_1 = [[1, 'John'], [2, 'Mcquin'], [4, 'Paul'], [7, 'Jimmy'], [9, 'Coco'], [11, 'Coco']]
lst_2 = [[3, 'Mcquin', 1], [6, 'Paul', 6], [5, 'John', 15], [12, 'Coco', 18], [8, 'Jimmy', 24], [10, 'Coco', 24]]
```

What is the most efficient way of sorting `lst_1` based on the second value in the sublist of `lst_2` (`lst_2[i][1]`)?
Preferred output:

```
[[2, 'Mcquin'], [4, 'Paul'], [1, 'John'], [9, 'Coco'], [7, 'Jimmy'], [11, 'Coco']]
```

It doesn't matter if there are duplicates of the same name (Coco in this case). Also, the lists will always contain the same names like here.

Comment: How does an entry of `lst_1` map to `lst_2` And your preferred output is **not** based on `lst_2[i][1]`.

Comment: but it is? it's ordered following the order of the first occurrence of every name in the second list

Comment: by your logic: `[2, 'Mcquin']` is provided by `'Paul'` (`lst_2[1][1]`) - what kind of sorting did you imagine?

Comment: @liliscent For example, if `lst_2[0][1] == 'Mcquin'` then the new sorted `lst_1[0]` should be the sublist that contains `'Mcquin'`

Comment: Please edit your question to make the sort order as specific as possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Edit: I think I have an **`O(n)`** solution!*

---

Originally, I thought we could create a `dictionary` of the names and the indexes they should appear in the final list based on `lst_2`. Then we could create the final list by sorting `lst_1` - giving an `O(n log(n))` solution.

However, the problem with that method is that there are duplicate names in `lst_2`! Also, this new method even has a better time complexity!

---

First we create a dictionary *based on `lst_1`* where each `key` is a name and each value is a <strike>`list`</strike> [`collections.deque`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.deque) (thanks RoadRunner) of the numbers which correspond to that name.

By using a `deque`, we maintain the ordering of those elements in `lst_1` with the same names. Also, we have the ability to call `.popleft` on a `deque` in `O(1)` time.

This then allows us to iterate over `lst_2` (removing the need for any sorting as it is already in order) and append to a new list the name followed by the first entry of values in the dictionary we created.

If we use `.popleft()` to get the first element, we also remove it meaning that when that name next comes up in `lst_2`, we get the next value in `lst_1`.

So, here's the code:

```
import collections
vals = {}
for v, n in lst_1:
    vals.setdefault(n, collections.deque()).append(v)

#vals == {'Paul': [4], 'Coco': [9, 11], 'John': [1], 'Mcquin': [2], 'Jimmy': [7]}
#        (each key here ^^ is actually a deque but it's easier to see with lists)
r = []
for _,n,_ in lst_2:
    r.append([n, vals[n].popleft()])
```

giving `r` (for result) as:

```
[['Mcquin', 2], ['Paul', 4], ['John', 1], ['Coco', 9], ['Jimmy', 7], ['Coco', 11]]
```

Comment: the three last entries should be `[12, 'Coco', 18], [8, 'Jimmy', 24], [10, 'Coco', 24]`

Comment: @JohnSmith See the updated answer, it now works properly (sorry for the mistake before) and is even more efficient!

Comment: `pop(0)` is O(N) I believe. If you use `popleft()` from `deque` this would be a O(N) solution, since it's O(1) instead when popping from the front. Nice job :-).

Comment: @RoadRunner Very interesting, led me to reading up a lot about CPython's implementation of `lists`! I have updated the answer to use `deque` now.

Answer (score 4):

If both your lists have the same amount of names, you could store the indices of each element in a [`collections.defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict), then pop off each index and use it as the sort key when an item is found during sorting.

**Demo:**

```
from collections import defaultdict, deque

lst_1 = [[1, 'John'], [2, 'Mcquin'], [4, 'Paul'], [7, 'Jimmy'], [9, 'Coco'], [11, 'Coco']]
lst_2 = [[3, 'Mcquin', 1], [6, 'Paul', 6], [5, 'John', 15], [12, 'Coco', 18], [8, 'Jimmy', 24], [10, 'Coco', 24]]

sort_map = defaultdict(deque)
for i, x in enumerate(lst_2):
    sort_map[x[1]].append(i)

result = sorted(lst_1, key=lambda x: sort_map[x[1]].popleft())

print(result)
```

**Output:**

```
[[2, 'Mcquin'], [4, 'Paul'], [1, 'John'], [9, 'Coco'], [7, 'Jimmy'], [11, 'Coco']].
```

**Note:** You can use [`collections.deque`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/collections.html#collections.deque) to pop off elements from the beginning in constant time, as shown above. This minor improvement allows the above solution to remain at overall O(NlogN), which is the cost of sorting.

Answer (score 1):

Very not pythonish but still easy to understand and working:

```
lst_new = []
for item in lst_2:
    name = item[1]
    for item2 in lst_1:
        if name == item2[1]:
            lst_new.append(list.copy(item2))
            lst_1.remove(item2)
            #item2[1] = "" is also an option but it's worse for long inputs
            break
```

Output:

```
>>> lst_new
[[2, 'Mcquin'], [4, 'Paul'], [1, 'John'], [9, 'Coco'], [7, 'Jimmy'], [11, 'Coco']]
```

Comment: Explain the downvote because this works as OP intended

Comment: The only reason I can see for the downvote is that this is `O(nm)`. Other than that, its a completely valid solution. I think its a pretty creative solution.

Comment: ah I didn't think of `item[2] = ""`. Nice one!

Comment: @RoadRunner yeah it's not so efficient but if the lists are going to be not very long I don't see a reason to write a more complicated algorithm

Comment: @JohnSmith actually, you could simply do `lst_1.remove(item2)` and make the algorithm faster for longer lists

Answer (score 0):

Given two lists:

```
xs = [[4, 'a'], [3, 'b'], [7, 'c'], [10, 'd']]
ys = [ 7, 3, 4, 10]
```

the following line sorts the list `xs` by the order of items in `ys`:

```
[x for y in ys for x in xs if x[0] == y]
```

Result:

```
>>> [x for y in ys for x in xs if x[0] == y]
[[7, 'c'], [3, 'b'], [4, 'a'], [10, 'd']]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
l = sorted(lst_1, key=lambda x: [i[2] for i in lst_2 if i[1] == x[1]][0])
```

Explanation: We're sorting with the key being the 3rd value (i[2]) from lst_2 only if the 2nd value matches the argument (i[1] == x[1]).

Note that if a value that exist in lst_1 is missing from lst_2 an error will result (perhaps justifiably, since a key is missing).